# problems with to rotate an image (image in different positions from desktop to mobile)

Tags: css, vue.js, rotation, vuetify.js

I want to rotate an image, because on mobile it is in a position
and on desktop it is on another but I'm using the same class in both (imagem), so i cant go to css.

I need to rotate the image on mobile 
mobile part

```
<v-img
          class="imagem d-flex d-sm-none"
          src="imagens/doacao/meninomobile.svg"
          style="height: 400px;"
        ></v-img>
```

im using @media also.

```
    @media (max-width: 599px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

so i dont know what to do, im was thinking of v-if inside of v-img but isnt working, im trying rotate(6.5deg) inside of style but it doesnt work too and inside of v-img class but also doesnt work.

Comment: You could probably achieve this with CSS. Use a media query to detect mobile devices, and the `transform: rotate(180deg);`

Comment: @bassxzero feel free to post that one as an answer.